# if statement error: int conversion to boolean

Tags: c#, int, boolean

```
public static void Main(string[] args) // this is a method called "Main". It is called when the program starts.
{

    Random numberGenerator = new Random();

    int userInput1;
    int userInput2;
    int finalUserInput;
    int theCorrectAnswer;

    //generating random numbers. from 1 to 10. 11 is exclusive.
    userInput1 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 11);
    userInput2 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 11);

    //Asks the user to solve the multiplication problem.
    Console.Write("What is " + userInput1 + " x " + userInput2 + " ?");
        finalUserInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        theCorrectAnswer = userInput1 * userInput2;

    if(finalUserInput = theCorrectAnswer)
```

Hi. When I try to set up a if statement with conditions, an error message pops up saying you cannot implicitly convert int to boolean. I'm not trying to do that at all. I'm quite lost. Help!

Comment: You are doing `finalUserInput = theCorrectAnswer`, which is assignment. As consequence your if winds up being "if(int)" and that is why you are getting that error. You should replace `=` with `==`.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a value of `theCorrectAnswer` variable to `finalUserInput` by using single `=`. And this statement returns the value – integer one.

You need to use `==` to compare two values.

It's a typo or a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You need the equality operator == for your case but you are using the assignment operator = in if statement:

```
if (finalUserInput = theCorrectAnswer)
```

Should be like below:

```
if (finalUserInput == theCorrectAnswer)
```